# hyper-v hardware problem

Tags: hyper-v

I have built a PC with following characteristics: CPU - Intel Pro Core 2 Quad 9550 (which should support virtualization), Motherboard - Intel DX48BT2 (which I guess should also support VT), RAM - 8 G. DDR3. Now I am trying to install hyper-v role in Server 2008 64-bit edition and I got a message: "Server Manager has detected that the processor on this computer is not compatible with Hyper-V. To install this role, the processor must have a supported version of hardware virtualization, and that feature must be turned on in the BIOS". When I look at the BIOS I can see XD settings which is set correctly and virtual appliance in which all options set to Enabled. However, I do not see virtualization options and I have no idea how virtual appliance is correlated with virtualization. But anyway Hyper-V does not work. Can somebody tell me what is wrong in my hardware configuration.

Answer (score 3):

XD is execute bit disable. You're looking for VT, or Vanderpool Technology in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Stating the obvious: there is a reality disconnect between:

> Intel Pro Core 2 Quad 9550 (which
>   should support virtualization),
>   Motherboard - Intel DX48BT2 (which I
>   guess should also support VT)

and

> However, I do not see virtualization options

I suggest checking facts. if your processor supports VT, then maybe a bios update helps.